# How to use linqkit like

Tags: c#, linq, linqkit

```
data Name{"divan","dîvan","divân","dîvân" }
```

I want to something like `select * from data where Name like % d_v_n %` in linq

then the expected result would be `"divan","dîvan","divân","dîvân"`

```
 //this linqkit code
 var searchPredicate = PredicateBuilder.False<ViewModelListManuscript>();    
 searchPredicate = searchPredicate.Or(m =>  m.TRTitle.ToLower().Contains("d_v_n"));    
 query = query.AsExpandable().Where(searchPredicate);
```

empty result

Comment: Why use PredicateBuilder if you only have one predicate?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use `SqlMethods.Like(matchExpression,pattern)` like this:

```
 var results = from dl in DataList
               where SqlMethods.Like(dl.Name,"%d_v_n%")
               select dl;
```

Comment: when I use SqlMethods,query is distorted